# Class file for jakarta.servlet.ServletException not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jakarta-migration

I am trying to create a springboot application with springsecurity and I am facing jakarta servlet error. First, I dont understand why we need Jakarta or the Servlet. Below is the full error

```
java: cannot access jakarta.servlet.ServletException
  class file for jakarta.servlet.ServletException not found
```

I learnt that with SpringBoot Application, I do not have to explicitly add Jakarta Servlet dependency, that Springboot manages the container and servlet. I have tried changing versions of springboot and spring as advised by Chat GPT but I still can't pinpoint the problem. I need help please. Below is my Pom.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
<!--        <relativePath/> -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringSecurityMaven</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringSecurityMaven</name>
    <description>SpringSecurityMaven</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>



        <!-- H2 Database -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.224</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Thymeleaf Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring6</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.0-M1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.11</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-dependency-tree</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>tree</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: When did you get the error?

Comment: When I ran my springboot application

Answer (score 0):

You are using Spring boot 2 and this has best match with Spring 5 dependencies. Furthermore, Spring boot 3 has best match with Spring 6. I would recommand you to remove all dependency versions for Spring dependencies and let Maven manage it by itself.

Your pom.xml dependencies tag would look like that:

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <!-- H2 Database -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Thymeleaf Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring6</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Same changes for plugins

I would also suggest to you to use Java 11 instead Java 17. I think this is more approprite for your Spring boot version.

Comment: I have removed the versions for all the spring boot dependencies but the jakarta error message is still there, and it is not making my springboot application run.

Comment: What happens if you are using Java 11 instead Java 17 ? Answer updated

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot dependencies should be updated with

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
<relativePath/> 
    </parent>
```

Comment: I have changed the version to 3.2.1 but the error still persist.

Comment: Updated, also remove  `<version>` from Spring Boot artifacts to let the Maven choose the current versions. How do you build it? Do you have a parent `pom.xml`?